# Computing integral of $x+y+z$ over the unit cube

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

Compute the integral:

$$\iint_\sigma (x+y+z)\,\mathrm dS $$

on the cube $0\le x\le1, 0\le y\le1, 0\le z \le 1$.

I am really confused how should I compute it as I used to just take the projection of $\ z $ on the $\ xy $ plane but here the projection is just a square from $\ 0 $ to $\ 1 $. Trying to compute $\ \int_0^1 \int_0^1 (x + y) dy dx $ doesn't lead me to the right answer.

Comment: ...and "the right answer" is?

Comment: Oh sorry, the correct answer is 9.

Comment: Why the integral is $dS$ not $dV$? Do you want to calculate on the boundary surface?

Comment: Is the a volume or area integral???

Comment: Yes boundary surface I believe. Wasn't sure what is the correct term in english.

Comment: I think you are pretty close, but note that $(x+y)$ only works for when $z=0$, what should it be on the side where $z=1$?

Comment: is it $\ x+y+1 $ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\displaystyle\int_0^1 \int_0^1 (x + y + 0)\ dy\ dx
=\int_0^1 x + \frac12\ dx
=1$　>>　the value on the plane $z=0$.

$\displaystyle\int_0^1 \int_0^1 (x + y + 1)\ dy\ dx
=1 + \int_0^1 \int_0^1 (x + y)\ dy\ dx
=2$　>>　the value on the plane $z=1$.

The correct answer is $3\cdot(1 + 2) = 9$. The $3$ means that there are three dimensions. (same value by symmetry)

Comment: Hey Alan, You might get a bit more traction if you expand your answer a bit more. (eg where 3(2+1) coming from?) Why are you calculating the first integral?

Comment: I can't see where or how the "The correct answer" part comes from...

Comment: I've added more explanations... I think this problem is not quite difficult though

Comment: @AlanTsai It is for the OP, otherwise I doubt he would have asked it...